json field not mapped correctly with custom projection
i'm using postgresql with spring boot and I have a json column defined like this
ALTER TABLE core."foo"
    ADD COLUMN if not exists config json;

the Foo entity is mapped like this
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

  ...
  @Type(JsonType.class)
  private Config config;

the Foo entity contains a lot of columns so I use a custom dto to perform some optimized select
  @Query(
  """
    SELECT new path.to.package.FooProjection(
      f.id,
      f.config
    )
    FROM Foo f
    WHERE ...
  """)
  Optional<FooProjection> fetchMinimalFoo(Long fooId);

the FooProjection is classic pojo with config field mapped like this
@Getter
@Builder
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FooProjection {

  private final Long id;
  private final Config config;

the issue is when the query is executed I got this error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot instantiate class 'path.to.package.FooProjection' 
(it has no constructor with signature [java.lang.Long, java.lang.Object], and not every argument has an alias)

It consider the json field as an object !!

Why m.config and nog f.config. So either you are missing a join or something like that or this code is too much dumbed down to be useful in your question.

@M.Deinum no it was just a typo when i write the question, in my production code i'm putting f.config (I've updated the question)

Use @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON), instead of @Type(JsonType.class)
Here is a full working example:
The entity:
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import org.hibernate.annotations.JdbcTypeCode;
import org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes;

@Entity
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    private Config config;

}

The projection is same as yours:
@Getter
@Builder
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FooProjection {

    private final Long id;
    private final Config config;
}

The config POJO:
@Data
public class Config {
    private String asd;
}

The query is same as yours, I only added @Param("fooId").
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {

    @Query(
            """
              SELECT new path.to.package.FooProjection(
                f.id,
                f.config
              )
              FROM Foo f
              WHERE f.id = :fooId
            """)
    Optional<FooProjection> fetchMinimalFoo(@Param("fooId") Long fooId);
}


can you explain me the difference between @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON) and @Type(JsonType.class)
